# Is Drywall needed on exterior wall of garage on concrete block, 2-story house in Florida

Tags: drywall, code-compliance, garage

We have a home inspector (selling house) stating they want us to put up drywall on an exterior wall in the garage. I know it's code for ceilings and the abutting walls to the interior, but do exterior walls need it?

It's a concrete wall with insulation strip on it.

Comment: Add a picture? It's not obvious to me what you mean by "with insulation strip on it" and that might impact the correct answer.

Comment: "We have a home inspector (selling house)"  *Home inspector is selling house?* **Have you asked the inspector to provide the documentation that states you are required to cover a cement wall with drywall?** Or, can you remove the "insulation strip"?

Answer (score 1):

Drywall on the inside of an exterior wall has not been required in any of the states I have lived, it is required for fire protection on stick built, but a concrete block wall has the appropriate fire ratings and should require nothing. call your fire marshal to verify local code as far as I know drywall is not required on an interior wall even from a garage to living space with block walls and your fire marshal or fire department can verify this. I think your inspector is nuts.

Comment: I don't know what "with insulation strip on it" is supposed to mean without a picture, but if there is exposed insulation rather than bare block wall, there may indeed be a reason to have drywall over it, as many types of insulation are flammable or partially flammable (paper face) when exposed.